# Function returns an empty DataTable, but I can see "individual" elements being imported

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I've been having trouble for a couple of hours with a function in C#. Basically I want to call a function with a file (a .csv file in this case with `;` delimited columns), and return the data contained in the .csv file as a DataTable (except the first line which contains the headers). For this I've tried:

```
private DataTable getDataTable(string file)
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable("Order_proposal_Internal_External");
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FileName"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Supplier"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Store"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity"));
    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Delivery_Date"));  

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
    lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        var cols = line.Split(';');

        if (cols.Length == 1)
            continue;

        DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();

        dr[0] = file;

        for (int cIndex = 1; cIndex + 1 < tbl.Columns.Count; cIndex++)
        {
            dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
            MessageBox.Show(cols[cIndex]);
        }
    }
    return tbl;
}
```

Here I can see that `MessageBox.Show(cols[cIndex]);` gets all data, except the first row (containing the headers, this is *intended*). The first column containing the FileName is not included in the output (this is *not* intended).

The table itself is empty as well when I print it out as a whole. This is also confirmed in a later stage, where I call Another function where I use this table as a parameter `t` and:

```
if (t.Rows == 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Fails at Point 5");
     return;
}
```

and when I run the program, it prints `Fails at Point 5`.

The .csv file used as a paramater for the function has the appearence:

```
supplier;store;item;quantity;delivery_date
13;1;411;12.0;20170322
80;1;415;3.0;20170322
```

Does anyone have any clue what I've failed to grasp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the call to add the row to the DataTable.Rows collection, just creating the DataRow doesn't add it to the Rows collection and your table remains empty.

```
DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
dr[0] = file;
for (int cIndex = 1; cIndex + 1 < tbl.Columns.Count; cIndex++)
{
    dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
    MessageBox.Show(cols[cIndex]);
}
tbl.Rows.Add(dr);   // < this one is needed
```

Also this line seems to be wrong

```
dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
```

Here the loop starts setting the loaded values from the column at index 2 (Store) skipping the column at index 1 (Supplier) It should be

```
dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex-1];
```

Note that the first element from splitted string (the Supplier code) is at index zero, so you should read from cIndex-1.

Also the ending condition of the for..loop is incorrect. In the CSV file you have 5 columns, in the table the columns are 6. The loop should go with

```
for (int cIndex = 1; cIndex < tbl.Columns.Count; cIndex++)
{
   dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex-1];
   ....
}
```

Comment: Adding `tbl.Rows.Add(dr); inside the foreach loop got me the error `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code` pointing at that line. Seems to be something wrong with the data types if I have interpreted the error correct?

Comment: I tested that just before I read this and the script executed. Now Im off to the next error! Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4):

`tbl.NewRow()` creates the new `TableRow` object, but doesn't add it to the table's `Rows` collection. It does exactly what it says on the tin, and no more. Adding it to `Rows` is a separate method call.

```
    DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();

    dr[0] = file;

    for (int cIndex = 1; cIndex + 1 < tbl.Columns.Count; cIndex++)
    {
        dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
    }

    //  Now that it's populated, add it to the table. 
    tb.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the row to the DataTable. When calling the NewRow method on the DataTable object it's creating a row with a schema that matches the row definition, but it's not actually added to it's internal collection.

```
        tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
```